# removing array javascript value sequentially from first index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array :

```
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava"];
```

and I want to remove array value sequentially from first index.
so it will produce:

```
[ "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
[ "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
[ "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
[ "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
[ "lemon", "guava" ]
[ "guava" ]
```

I've already tried this code:

```
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon",   "guava"];

runLoop = async () => {
for(const item of items){
        await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 1000 ));
        console.log(items);
        remove(items, item);
        console.log('------------');
    }
 }

 function remove(array, element) {
  console.log('deleting '+element);
  const index = array.indexOf(element);
  array.splice(index, 1);
 }
```

but the result it's not what I expected,
here is the result:

```
Array(6) [ "apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
Array(5) [ "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
Array(4) [ "orange", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava" ]
```

Comment: Why getting the index when it always removes the first element? Just use array.splice(0,1).

Comment: yes, you right, thank you so much @MauriceNino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that array iterable is *live* - if you invoke the iterator with `for..of` and mutate the array *while that iterator is still being used*, the resulting items iterated over will likely be unintuitive - some indicies may be missed. It's kind of like what's going on here:

```js
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon",   "guava"];
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  console.log('item: ', items[i]);
  items.splice(i, 1);
}
```

The loop only runs 3 times, because you're removing items from the array *while you're iterating over it*, so some indicies get skipped.

One possibility is to make a copy of the array first, when invoking the iterator with `for..of`, so that the iterator will always iterate over every item that was in the *original array* sequentially:

```js
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon",   "guava"];

runLoop = async () => {
  for(const item of items.slice()){
    await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( resolve, 300 ));
    console.log(items);
    remove(items, item);
    console.log('------------');
  }
}

function remove(array, element) {
  console.log('deleting '+element);
  const index = array.indexOf(element);
  array.splice(index, 1);
}
runLoop();
```

Comment: Explains it really well!

Answer (score 1):

You need to splice at index zero,

```
array.splice(0, 1);
```

or just shift the first element.

```
array.shift();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative can a recursive function and [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift) which removes the first element from an array

```js
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava"];

function removeElem(arr) {
  if (arr.length !== 1) {
    console.log(arr)
    arr.shift();

    removeElem(arr)
  } else {
    console.log(arr)
  }
}
removeElem(items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.slice to achieve this. When using splice, remember that it will affect the original array, which should not be done according to the functional approach of javascript. Functional programming doesn't recommend to mutate the original object.

```js
let items = ["apple", "orange", "watermelon", "blueberry", "lemon", "guava"];

for(let i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    console.log(items.slice(i,items.length));
 }
```